# ListView onScrollListener, Hide all the elements except one

Tags: java, android, listview

Im looking for a way to hide my listview when the user is in the top of the scroll and doesn't stop to scroll (Exactly like the new app of Uber, that show and hide the "Messages" part of the app.

My Listview is above of a FrameLayout. I was working with a onscrollListener but I don't know how to still notice the scroll from the user

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [this](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView) one.

It is the best tool I've used for scrollviews so far.

`ObservableScrollView` helps you in easier scroll handling.